# How do I change color of graphs with ggPredict in R? plot(b, colors="bw")?

Tags: r, graph, colors

I have made this model:

```
lm1 <- lm(respiration.rate.calf~length+abs_pres,data=data)
```

And tried to visualize it with `ggPredict`:

```
b<-ggPredict(lm1, se=TRUE)+labs(x="Calf length (m)", y="Calf respiration rate (breaths/min)")
plot(b)
```

However, the graphs I get are red and green but I have to print the graph in black and white. Does anyone know how to change line type (e.g. one solid and one dotted) or color (one bright and one dark) in `ggPredict`?

I have tried for 3 hours now and the last thing I tried was this but it does not work:

```
plot(b, colors="bw")
```

Comment: Or how I can add standard error to this function (where I have managed to change the color):

ggplot(data,aes(y=respiration.rate.calf,x=length))+labs(x="Calf length (m)", y="Calf respiration rate (breaths/min)")+geom_point()+
  stat_function(fun=without_inst,geom="line",color="black", size=1.5)+
  stat_function(fun=with_inst,geom="line",color="grey", size=1.5)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ggplot()` function and change the colors as you like

```
library(ggeffects)
library(ggplot2)
data(efc)
fit <- lm(barthtot ~ c12hour + bs(neg_c_7) * c161sex + e42dep, data = efc)

ggpredict(fit, terms = "c12hour")
mydf <- ggpredict(fit, se=TRUE)
mydf <- ggpredict(fit, terms = c("neg_c_7", "c161sex", "e42dep"))

ggplot(mydf, aes(x = x, y = predicted, colour = group)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon( aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, fill = group, color = NULL), alpha = .15) +
  facet_wrap(~facet) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00'))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "green"), name="fill")
```

[image]

Comment: You can replace `scale_color_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00'))+  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "green"), name="fill")` by `scale_colour_grey() +  scale_fill_grey()`